# A data forensic tools for android

Tags: security, sim-card, data-recovery

I have recently taken interest in digital forensics.  What is the best tool, or set of tools to obtain and analyze images of android phones?

Comment: I would imagine the same tools could be used as those for hard drives, assuming you can mount the microsd in a card reader? What specific tools are you looking to replace?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android

Comment: "What is the best" questions are generally off-topic for this site. Please review the [FAQ].