# Retrieve deleted file Android droid 2

Tags: file-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android)

I deleted a file from my droid 2 -Android 2.2. I am not trying to retrieve the file(jpg). I have used Astro to look at the file system and dumped all the camera pictures(as this picture was taken with the Motorola droid 2) but have not been able to retrieve the image.

Is there any way I can retrieve the image from the droid 2 that I have deleted ? This picture was taken on July 15th, 2011 before Google+ days.
I have Windows desktops at my disposal.

TIA,
Vijay

Comment: Vijay, is there any programming efforts involve in this..?

Comment: This is probably an off-topic question