# Do I have any chance to recover this video?

Tags: video, data-recovery, delete

Using Samsung Galaxy ACE s5830
Android 2.3.6

Well I made a mistake. I was recording an important video with my smartphone (the default video recorder) and then I put the cellphone close to my chest. I noticed later that the video stopped but i thought it was saved. seems like somehow the jacket touched a cancel button (not delete) and then ok. odd but it happened.
now i dont find the video.
My question is if anyone knows if i have any chance to recover the video from a place in the SD memory, probaly using an forensic tool to recover deleted files. I mean if the data was being created somewhere in a temp file until its done, It could be recovered but as this is android i dont have idea.
The video was important so I'll try anything.
NOTE: checking in windows, it shows the modification date in the folder DCIM\Camera, corresponding to the moment i was recording. So at least there was access to that specific folder.

thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android and try one of the answers there.

Answer (score -1):

If the video is recorded, then it will be saved to your phone. But for your case, what I guess is that the video is not recorded.

Answer (score -1):

Check out a [linux] tool called foremost - that ought to do it.

Comment: Please leave an answer why this tool is helpfull in the context of the question asked.