# Using adb backup to recover files in Android

Tags: adb, data-recovery

I encountered a situation similar to the question:
[How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android)

I have a Sensation XE which is not rooted.

From the previously linked question, is there away that I can achieve step 2 in the highest rated answer using `adb backup`?

> Step 2: Acquire an image of that block device with `dd`:
>
> ```
> dd if=/dev/<blockdevice> of=/sdcard/image bs=4096
> ```

Comment: @Izzy and if it is possible to recover files by the following steps? 1. `temp root` my Sensation XE by the method in the section "STEPS TO RUN THIS TOOL" in the link: [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1661631), under a windows os, without doing the s-off steps in this link; 2. connect it to a linux system to run the `dd` command as stated  in the highest rated answer; 3. and then back to windows to run  temp_root_remove.bat to my Sensation XE.

Comment: @Dan Hulme Thank you for editing my question which makes it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. `dd` operates on block-level (it makes a 1:1 copy of the data blocks), while `adb backup` works on file-level. The two are not compatible.

Comment: @user36987 Similarly, file recovery programs for a desktop computer require admin privileges, as they also work at the block level. The data exists (blocks), but the meta-data (file) is gone, so you need full access to bypass the upper layer and go deeper to the bare hard drive.

Comment: @user36987 Glad we could help! You're welcome to "accept" the answer (click the check-mark next to it :).