# temp root to acquire a .dd image of my android phone

Tags: rooting, data-recovery

I have a Sensation XE which is not rooted. (hboot 1.29, android 4.0.3)

I found a recovering method in the highest ranked answer in this post: [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15869/how-can-i-recover-a-deleted-file-on-android).

From the above post, it's necessary to root my phone, but for some reasons, I don't want a permanently root.

Is it possible to follow steps 1~5 in this post
[[GUIDE] Juopunutbear S-OFF NO HTCDEV UNLOCK | ROOT (1.2x HBOOTS)--NEW: ONE CLICK ROOT](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1661631) to temporarily root my phone, ...

> 1.get this temproot-sensation-windows zip file
>
> TEMPROOT ZIP
>
> 2.Extract temproot-sensation-windows.zip into a directory on your computer.
>
> 3.Plug your HTC SENSATION/XE/4G into your computer via USB. (keep the connection in "charging" mode)
>   Recommended: Plug your device’s USB cable into the back of your computer if you’re using a desktop PC.
>
> 4.Enable USB Debugging on your HTC sensation. Settings >> Develop Options >>USB debugging (checked)
>
> 5.Double click temp_root.bat to run the script and wait until it completes. Don't touch the device during the entire process.

and then follow the steps 1~3 in the highest ranked answer to recovery the deleted files in my phone?

> 1. Find out on which block device the file was on. Via `mount`
> 2. Acquire and image of that block device with dd: dd `if=/dev/<blockdevice> of=/sdcard/image bs=4096`
>
> 3.Get a data recovery forensics tool and let it search `/sdcard/image` for the lost file. You can of course try to run multiple tools on the image. Formemost and Scalpel are a good start.

Comment: If you try, you will find out. As long as you don't reboot the device between temp-rooting and image-aquiring, this should work I'd say.

Comment: You should be able to access some of the files on the internal hard drive. I think it will be next to impossible to get a full image of the hard drive without root. Android won't want you snooping in some of it's high-security folders like `/boot`