# Recovering deleted pictures

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, data-recovery, photos

I recently deleted all of my pictures by mistake from my samsung galaxy s4.
I went into my files and documents and deleted not realising it would delete all my pics!

Is there a way for me to recover them?

My phone is not rooted. I have not taken any pictures since but have received pictures through whatsapp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I recover a deleted file on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15869/16575) Also take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) for further hints.

Comment: Were the photos on a removable card?

Comment: Important: You know that writing new photos to the memory with the deleted photos is very dangerous; But it's as dangerous to writa any other data to the same area of memory. That area will be either a memory card, or a part (partition) of some internal flash memory. If you use a separate sd card to save photos, and nothing else is saved there: all good. But if it is on a shared partition or card, like a completely different directory (folder) on some common memory - writing anything there will still overwrite photo data.

Answer (score 0):

Especially for recovering JPEG files, I would strongly propose to try the recovery software [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). It was originally developed to do exactly that, recover not files, but JPEG photos, on the disk - not even looking at the file system. As long as nothing got overwritten, it should recover a large part I expect.

I did not need it myself yet, but the way it works makes very much sense.

Runs on Linux, Windows, Mac, licensed under GPL v2+

`PhotoRec` comes in one package with the related software `TestDisc` - the package file named testdisk-* should contain both programms: [TestDisk & PhotoRec Download](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

*Note on recovering other files than photos:*
PhotoRec should work well for many other file types, the programm PhotoRec was developed to be good at recovering photos, but was soon extended to work with other file formats with some kind of predictable structure too.

---

Interestingly, the open source license has a real practical relevance in this case: If the card is not removable, and you can not get an image from it to be used in a PC - you could, theoretically, compile/port it for your phone, to run it there in text mode per ssh connection from a PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Dumpster - Recycle Bin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baloota.dumpster&hl=en)
it might help you to recovery all your Data (Restore deleted pictures, music files, videos and much more)

Comment: Seems like it could be helpful, yes - but... **Wow!** I took a look at the programm, and stopped reading the description at the fifth line: "No need to backup your data." That's really the most brilliant advice one can give to someone who just lost data...

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Well this app helped me many times. so, i recommend this to everyone. If i helped you you can vote my answer up to help others.

Comment: Oh, I was just about to edit the comment to say that I did see it may be useful here indeed! ( The cynical part was just more urgent, somehow :) ) Edited the above, only missing some more bold... :)

Comment: I started to read a little more on Dumpster; It needs that it was running already when the files were deleted. So it **will not help** the to solve the problem here, as it was not installed then.

Comment: Try it by yourself by deleting some file which you dont want on your phone then try that app.