# How to undelete photos in a Samsung galaxy S4 active?

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, photos

How to undelete photos in a Samsung galaxy S4 active? I have deleted a folder on the phone with pictures in it and I would really like get them back. Not on SD card but in the phones memory.

Answer (score 0):

recovery of deleted contents stored in the internal storage is difficult at the best of times and darn near impossible the rest. The issue lies in how you access the storage medium without root is impossible to my knowledge to access the storage space as a raw partition for use with data recovery tools. As with all recovery the more you use the device the less your odds of recovery are that said if you do not clear your cache often you should be able to at the very least recover some of the pics even if your not rooted by looking thought your high rez thumbnails sure the resolution is a major step down from the originals but it's better then nothing. Suggested reading https://android.stackexchange.com/a/84747/122342